# How do I find multiple modes in a Java ArrayList?

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

I'm having trouble properly displaying all of the modes in an ArrayList. In the program the user inputs grades and you have to find the modes and also accommodate for multimodal data sets.
This is what I have so far. I have a loop to take the grade values that are modes and place them in a mode List, but when I print it it prints them several times over and over instead of only printing the numbers one at a time. Also we have to use an ArrayList so it is dynamic. Appreciate any help!

```
public static void getMode(ArrayList <Integer> grades) {
    ArrayList <Integer> modes= new ArrayList<>();
    int maxCount = 0;
    for (int c = 0; c<grades.size(); c++) {
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<grades.size(); i++) {
            if(grades.get(i) == grades.get(c)) { counter++; }
            if(counter > maxCount) {
                maxCount = counter;
                modes.clear();
                modes.add(grades.get(c));
            }
            else if(counter==maxCount) {
                modes.add(grades.get(c));
            }
        }
    }
    for(int c = 0; c<grades.size(); c++) {
        System.out.println(modes.get(c));
    }
}
```

OUTPUT(if modes are 89,76):

```
89  
89  
76  
76  
76  
76
```

Comment: Here you have an O(n^2) algorithm to count, for each grade in the list, how many times it happens. However, if say the grade 1 appears ten times, then you will count it as the mode for each of the ten occurrences. A more sensible way would be to build a hash table that counts every grade, and then look for the most frequent. If grades are integers in a known range, you don't even need a hash table, an array will do (that's then like a counting sort).

Comment: Thanks, we aren't allowed to use hash table for this question and also we can't use arrays only array lists

Comment: Please add your expected input and output for clarification. Moreover purpose of  modes.clear() is not clear. And why do you use last grades.size() to iterate final for-loop ?

Comment: @Md.KawserHabib The purpose of `modes.clear()` is simply to remove all previously "known" modes if a more frequent grade is found, as it's the new mode.

Comment: A possibility: the algorithm will still be poor, but if you start the inner loop at `c` instead of `0`, then at least modes will appear only once: the subsequent attempts will "see" fewer occurrences, so they won't be catched as modes. Re my previous comment, note that using an array list instead of an array is absolutely not a problem, you just need to be sure grades are in a (preferably small) fixed range.

Answer (score -1):

If what you want to do - is to print each number maximum of 1 time - then you have to ensure on uniqueness of values.
There is a Set interface that guarantees that it will contain unique elements.
Here is sample code that takes given collection, creates relevant Set (to ensure numbers are not duplicated) - and prints all the elements

```
Set<Integer> modes = new HashSet<>(list);
modes.forEach(System.out::println);
```